# Node request module with fs.createWriteStream() creates an empty file

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, node-request

I'm trying to upload an external url to my server. Here's what I got so far

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var path = require('path');
const imagesFolder = 'downloadedAssets/imgs';

function download(url, dest, filename, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest + "/" + filename + path.extname(url));

    request( {url: url}, function(err, response) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            return;
        }

        response.pipe(file);

        file.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            file.end();
        });
        file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close(cb);
        });
   });
}
```

and then executing the function...

```
var url = 'http://pngimg.com/uploads/spongebob/spongebob_PNG44.png';

download(url, imagesFolder, 'sponge', function onComplete(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('image uploaded to server');
    }
});
```

This doesn't throw any errors, and it creates a file name sponge.png, but the file is empty. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You might have mixed up the examples on the official website

Try using `pipe()` like below.

```
function download(url, dest, filename, cb) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest + "/" + filename + path.extname(url));

    request( {url: url}).pipe(file);
}
```